# Dynamic waiting for element to become clickable not working

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, rpa

I have written a function as following

```
public static WebElement waitForElementToBeClickable(WebDriver driver, WebElement webElement, int seconds) {
    
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, seconds);
    WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(webElement));
    element.click();
    return element;
    
}
```

Now i am importing this function and using it as following

```
private String loginButton = "btnActive";
private String home = "//a[@id='pt1:_UIShome']";
WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.id(loginButton));
libraryUtils.waitForElements.waitForElementToBeClickable(driver, login, 20).click();
WebElement homeButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath(home));
libraryUtils.waitForElements.waitForElementToBeClickable(driver, homeButton, 20).click();
```

The login button is clicked but then after going to the next page i get the following error -

> org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

The Xpath is right, I have checked that. And when I use `element.click()`, that also works but then that would require me to manually enter the sleep time, which is what I'm doing. I would like this to be dynamic. Appreciate any help or suggestions.

Comment: Does element located with `//a[@id='pt1:_UIShome']` XPath presented on the first page, where the loginButton presented?

Comment: Can you share a link to the web site?

Comment: Hey sorry, im not allowed to share the link, but no the element with //a[@id='pt1:_UIShome'] is located on the page after i log in

Comment: OK, does this element in the view or you have to scroll to it in order to bring it to the visible screen? Is there some kind of pop-up, spinner etc initially above it?

Comment: Its in view, dont need to scrool or anything

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes JS had not been finished running, and if you try to interact with the **web element** or **web elements** you would see `staleElemenent exception`.

However the below solution may work for you :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@id='pt1:_UIShome']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='pt1:_UIShome']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly it will be not a nice, but I see no stable solution other that adding some sleep there.
So, please try this:

```
private String loginButton = "btnActive";
private String home = "//a[@id='pt1:_UIShome']";
WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.id(loginButton));
libraryUtils.waitForElements.waitForElementToBeClickable(driver, login, 20).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(home));
libraryUtils.waitForElements.waitForElementToBeClickable(driver, homeButton, 20);
try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
driver.findElement(By.xpath(home)).click();
```

Comment: im already adding sleep when to pause it manually, i wanted to do it dynamically so that it would work on multiple machines regardless of delay in internet speed. The thing is i have to add sleep to a lot more places not just this. But thank you.

Comment: I understand. In case there is a dynamic DOM there I see no simple and stable solution for that. It's a known problem.

Comment: Please let me know if you find some clear and stable solution.

Comment: Yes, sure, if you do too then please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is that you are already doing `element.click()` in the `waitForElementToBeClickable` function and calling click again while calling this function.

`libraryUtils.waitForElements.waitForElementToBeClickable(driver, login, 20).click();`

Since you have already clicked while waiting for the element to be clickable, you shouldn't be clicking it again. I hope you got the answer for `StaleElementException`

Comment: WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.id(loginButton));
        libraryUtils.waitForElements.waitForElementToBeClickable(driver, login, 20);
                 
        WebElement homeButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath(home));
        libraryUtils.waitForElements.waitForElementToBeClickable(driver, homeButton, 20);
      
      
      WebElement payablesButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath(payables));
        libraryUtils.waitForElements.waitForElementToBeClickable(driver, payablesButton, 20);

Comment: i changed the code and im executing it as shown above, it clicks on the homeButton element but it does not click on the payablesButton element. I get the following error - org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <a id="groupNode_payables_1" class="app-nav-label top-nav-label" role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="-1">...</a> is not clickable

Comment: The reason for this error is that some other element child or parent is overlapping the element you are trying to click. 


Couple of ways to fix are: 


`element = driver.find_element_by_css('div[class*="class_name"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)`

OR

`element = driver.find_element_by_css('div[class*="class_name"]')
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element ).click(element ).perform()`